# URL conventions for Maps on Windows Phone 7

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, dictionary, geocoding

What is the best practice for opening a map from the mobile internet explorer on windows phone 7? On BlackBerry you use a JavaScript method and on Android/iOS you simply link to a google maps URL.

I am planning to integrate the different ways of opening maps into my mobile geo javascript library and don't have a windows phone device.

http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/

Thanks,
Stan Wiechers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the maps: protocol for WP7.  I haven't found any documentation but this works.

```
<a href="maps:Vancouver V5L 4G1"></a>

<a href="maps:49.275267 -122.988617"></a>
```

Comment: i posted up a bunch of my findings [here](http://www.habaneros.com/Blog/Posts/Opening_native_map_apps_from_the_mobile_browser.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a built in way to link to the maps application from within a webpage on a device (or emulator). (Nor is it possible from other apps either.)

I'd recommend linking directly to a mobile Bing page. Such as the following which searches / shows a map for "London":

http://m.bing.com/search/search.aspx?A=mapdetails&L=London

Comment: Thanks much, this seems to be quite a missing feature. I will add in bing maps, assume that works better then google maps. Do you happen to have a bing URL convention document? Would be great. In the library i would like that users can open a map via a query and via a lat/lon address.

Comment: @Stan It doesn't look like Lat/Long is a supported format (http://m.bing.com/search/search.aspx?A=modifylocation)

Comment: @Stan sorry couldn't find a URL format document. Try asking at http://www.bing.com/community/bingsearch/f/12244.aspx